# How to trigger an email for inconsistent values

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I am completely fresh to salesforce (started two days ago) and the apex is really killing me, so please explain to me like in a 3 year old:)
I want to send an email to the user when a specific object of 3 objects is different, so if "b" is an object connected to "a", the trigger will send an email if the third object is different, say "c" in one case, and "d" in another, something like this:
a -> b <- c
a -> b <- d => because its not c, its inconsistent and sends an email

if I were writing in python it would look something like this:

```
for checkObject1 in listOfObjects1:
    if object1 == checkObject1:
        for checkObject2 in listOfObjects2-ofObject1:
           if object2 == checkObject2:
               for checkObject3 in listOfObjects3-ofObjects2-ofObject1:
                  if object3 != checkObject3:
                      send_email
```

Thanks :)

Comment: welcome to salesforce and the salesforce.stackexchange site! Some close votes are indicating your question may not be as clear to understand as you think. Would you mind trying to clarify it further ?

Comment: It helps sometimes to state your prior programming experience, so that those answering can gauge the level of information and associated links for further reading accordingly. Also cover what resources you have read already, such as documentation, wiki etc from developer.force.com.

Comment: Thanks, to get specific, I am tracking students explanations to concepts, so a student object is a conjunction object to both "explanation" objects, and "concept" objects, so for instance a student may explain that "altruism" is "evolutionary" and later say that it is "only humans" (both "explanation" objects) if there is an inconsistency in the students explanation I wan't to trigger an email pointing out that he explained it in one way here, and another there

Comment: What is the context when you'll be doing this checking?  Is this an interactive check when the student tries to enter or save the answer to a question?  Some other context?  It would be helpful to understand a bit more of the big picture here -- what kind of app are you building, and how does this functionality fit into it?

Comment: this app follows the students explanation to concepts, and helps the teacher construct a personalized exam based on how the student understands the material, I want this trigger to send an email the second the student adds another explanation to a concept